# Can anyone help me to fix this line of code?

Tags: python

I need to use a list comprehension to build a list of features from the columns of `data` that are *not* any of 'Name', 'Region', 'state', or 'AdultWeekend'. Can anyone help to fix this?

```
features = [data.columns for column in data.columns if column not in ['Name', 'Region', 'state', 'Adultweekend']]
```

Comment: Try to build your question titles so someone reading it can know the specific technical problem its answers show how to solve. Remember, the goal of asking a question here is to build a knowledge base, so the next person with the same problem doesn't _need_ to ask a new question! That means making your questions easy to find, and choosing a good title is an important part of that.

Comment: ...another thing that would be an improvement is including the error your existing code has as part of the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that `column` before the `for` keyword, not `data.columns`. You want to collect the various values of `column` over the different loop iterations.

```
features = [column for column in data.columns if column not in ['Name', 'Region', 'state', 'Adultweekend']]
```